# Browser history not working in electron app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, electron, webpack-2

I am using the **react-router v3**. My website works fine with **browserHistory**, But the same application ( with browserHistory ) not working in electron app. hashHistory works well but i can not use it because i have multiple applications on my web platform that are using browserHistory. This is why i can not afford any disturbance with the code base. Want to keep it same for **web** and for **electron** app.

At first browserHistory was also not working in the web app but then i changed the ngnix configuration which let the browserHistory works. I am presuming that i have to change the configurations of the electron like i did with ngnix. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try use `HashHistory`, it's add a # in your link.

Link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter